# Google Cloud Pub_Sub

Tags: android, google-cloud-pubsub

Hello Everyone,

```
I have create gmail app and complete all types of functionality but one functionality not implemented this one is mail receive in our gmail app.
```

Me search any types solution for receive mail and i have found one solution is google cloud Pub/Sub but this pub/sub how to implemented in our app is not idea show please tell me any one how to used pub/sub in android.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Pub/Sub is not the right choice for receiving messages on Android. The service is designed for inter-service communication. Using it on Android would present two problems:

1. The [limit on the number of topics and subscriptions per project](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits). Only 10,000 topics and subscriptions are allowed and only 10,000 subscriptions per topic. If you plan to scale out to many devices, you will run up against these limits quickly.
2. Security/authentication issues. You would need to ship the credentials within the Android application and so you will either have to generate service accounts for every individual device or use the same one across all devices. What do you do if those credentials are compromised? In the former case, you have to keep track of all of them and revoke the right one. In the latter case, revoking the privileges means all of your devices stop working.

You need something like [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to send data to Android devices. You may use Cloud Pub/Sub as a means to generate notifications out of GMail, but the subscriber would be another server-side application or perhaps a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) that passes the notification on via Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: So tell me another way for recceive incoming mail our android app.our android app create using fully gmail apis.